# How to drop trigger using sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js

This is Sequelize migration

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = {
      up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {  
        );
      },

      down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {       
      }
    };
```

Comment: Please read the document http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but you can access the `sequelize` object on the `queryInterface`. From there, you can do whatever you want. Since sequelize itself doesn't support the creation or removal of triggers (afaik), you will need to run a manual query:

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name ON table_name`);
```